# Is there a way to find sharepoint central admin login id

Tags: 2010

Is there a way to find the login ID of users who have access to central admin in SharePoint

Comment: If you have access to the servers in the farm, you could always check the SQL databases permissions. Any account that has Owner role on the AdminContent DB should grant you access to central admin.

Comment: Please post this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the servers in the farm, you could always check the SQL databases permissions. Any account that has Owner role on the Admin-content DB should grant you access to central admin.

No warranties that the account can access the actual servers though.

Answer (score 1):

Central Admin does not have a particular login. When the farm is created, some user accounts will be given administrator privileges and can access central admin.

If you need to access central administration, contact you IT support team and ask them to make you a farm administrator.

Comment: is there a way to get the user ids which have access to central admin?

Answer (score 1):

Are you the farm administrator of the farm ? If yes, you can view which users are farm admin and can access and do operations in the central admin.

Navigate to central admin site, choose security and then manage farm administrator group